# Decrypt TS file using OpenSSL (m3u8/EXT-X-KEY/EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE)

Tags: encryption, stream, openssl, aes, http-live-streaming

(Sorry in advance - my english is very bad)

I encrypted a couple of *.ts files in the past. Usually, there is a *.m3u8 with the necessary information, a key-file and the *.ts chunks.

Example:

File sources:

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430261-aes-content-protection

M3U8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
## Created with Unified Streaming Platform(version=1.6.7)
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="oceans.key"
#EXTINF:11, no desc
oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=236000-1.ts
```

...

What I do next is, download the key file "oceans.key" that is specified in #EXT-X-KEY and create a hexdump of the content:

```
cat oceans.key | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x" "\n"'

f571bfecfd1ab9adb05ce6fa030efd81
```

With the sequence number converted to HEX and left-padding 0 to fill up the '16 octet', I get the initial vector and execute this statement to decrypt the *.ts file:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in oceans_aes-audio\=65000-video\=236000-1.ts -out decrypted.ts -K f571bfecfd1ab9adb05ce6fa030efd81 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000001
```

It works like a charm. To make a long story short, I've some trouble get  these files decrypted:

https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/ajezM9HbgI3OI%2BY9%2BvUdJNnxYyXqGXX6K6jsNcrzYNc

The file named 'security' is the key file. When I hex-dump its content it is 17 octets instead of 16. Run the openssl command I get the following output:

```
hex string is too long
invalid hex key value
```

I compared the content of the file with some other files from this host and recognized that the last character is always the same (0x5e / ^). So, I removed it and tried again - my guess was that it is some kind of escape sequence / line-ending. No luck so far. The result is:

bad decrypt
140050579783384:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:529:

Here the complete command:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in media_1496546273.ts -out media_1496546273.decrypt.ts -K aaf36c79be1fad3977a4e8b19e48f038 -iv 00000000000000000000000000008E97
```

I thought about padding, nopadding, different cipher, ... No result so far. Chrome did play the files in flowplayer without any issues.

I would appreciate any help and hint to get on with this.

BR